# unlink multiple images while deleting category

Tags: php, mysqli

in my database when i delete an category all items that have same category will be deleted in the stock table so the images should be deleted too so i try out this code i do not think there is problem in my code because i tried it on 1 image row and it worked but when i comes to multiple rows it do not work here is my code

```
    if (isset($_POST['del'])) {

$del = mysqli_query($conn,"DELETE FROM category WHERE id='$id'");
if ($del) {
   $selstock = mysqli_query($conn," SELECT img FROM stock WHERE category='$name' ");
       while($row2=mysqli_fetch_assoc($selstock))
       {
       $img1=$row2['img'];
unlink("product_img/$img1");
}

header("location:addcategory.php");
}
}
```

**$name** is the category 
the folder path and URL are right it works with 1 row 
i watched other people doing that they did just like me but mine somehow does not work 
can any one tell me were did i went wrong

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements.

Comment: you are executing code on Linux or Windows ? as there could be permission issues..

Answer (score -1):

```
        if (isset($_POST['del'])) {

         // Image Query
   $selstock = mysqli_query($conn," SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE categoryId ='$id' ");
    if($selstock)
    {
     while($delImage=mysqli_fetch_assoc($selstock))
     {
       foreach($delImage as $key => $value)
       {
        $delLink = $value['img']; // first try
        /*$delLink = $value['img][$key]*/ // secound try
         unlink($delLink);
       }

     }

    }

    // Delete Query 

    $del = mysqli_query($conn,"DELETE FROM category WHERE id='$id'");

     if($del)
     {
      header("location:your.php");
     }

    }
```